# How to get the name and namespace of the pod created by deployment in golang

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have a project that needs to `intercept` and `handle` **pod creation**. When I parse the pod through `controller-runtime`, I find that the obtained pod `namespace and name` are **empty**.

```
# mutatingwebhook.yaml
  rules:
  - operations: ["CREATE"]
    apiGroups: [""]
    apiVersions: ["v1"]
    resources: ["pods"]
  failurePolicy: Fail
  sideEffects: None
  admissionReviewVersions: ["v1", "v1beta1"]
```

code:

```
func (p *PodInjector) Handle(ctx context.Context, req admission.Request) admission.Response {
    log := logf.FromContext(ctx)
    pod := &corev1.Pod{}
    // get incoming pod object
    err := p.decoder.Decode(req, pod)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err, "Failed to decode Pod")
        return admission.Errored(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    }
    log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("pod %s/%s is intercepted", pod.GetNamespace(), pod.GetName()))
    log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("pod %#v", pod))
```

output:

```
{"level":"info","ts":1660636409.8395593,"msg":"pod / is intercepted"}
{"level":"info","ts":1660636409.8398645,"msg":"pod &v1.Pod{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:\"Pod\", APIVersion:\"v1\"}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:\"\", GenerateName:\"nginx-deployment-7d849b6d9b-\", Namespace:\"\", SelfLink:\"\", UID:\"\", ResourceVersion:\"\", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{\"app\":\"nginx\", \"pod-template-hash\":\"7d849b6d9b\"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference{v1.OwnerReference{APIVersion:\"apps/v1\", Kind:\"ReplicaSet\", Name:\"nginx-deployment-7d849b6d9b\", UID:\"b22de271-8283-4409-a535-9640c96883a4\", Controller:(*bool)(0xc0007a08e7), BlockOwnerDeletion:(*bool)(0xc0007a08e8)}}, Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:\"\", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry{v1.ManagedFieldsEntry{Manager:\"kube-controller-manager\", Operation:\"Update\", APIVersion:\"v1\", Time:(*v1.Time)(0xc00073b740), FieldsType:\"FieldsV1\", FieldsV1:(*v1.FieldsV1)(0xc00073b758)}}}, Spec:v1.PodSpec{Volumes:[]v1.Volume{v1.Volume{Name:\"default-token-tkjfj\", VolumeSource:v1.VolumeSource{HostPath:(*v1.HostPathVolumeSource)(nil), EmptyDir:(*v1.EmptyDirVolumeSource)(nil), GCEPersistentDisk:(*v1.GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource)(nil), AWSElasticBlockStore:(*v1.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource)(nil), GitRepo:(*v1.GitRepoVolumeSource)(nil), Secret:(*v1.SecretVolumeSource)(0xc00059bc40), NFS:(*v1.NFSVolumeSource)(nil), ISCSI:(*v1.ISCSIVolumeSource)(nil), Glusterfs:(*v1.GlusterfsVolumeSource)(nil), PersistentVolumeClaim:(*v1.PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource)(nil), RBD:(*v1.RBDVolumeSource)(nil), FlexVolume:(*v1.FlexVolumeSource)(nil), Cinder:(*v1.CinderVolumeSource)(nil), CephFS:(*v1.CephFSVolumeSource)(nil), Flocker:(*v1.FlockerVolumeSource)(nil), DownwardAPI:(*v1.DownwardAPIVolumeSource)(nil), FC:(*v1.FCVolumeSource)(nil), AzureFile:(*v1.AzureFileVolumeSource)(nil), ConfigMap:(*v1.ConfigMapVolumeSource)(nil), VsphereVolume:(*v1.VsphereVirtualDiskVolumeSource)(nil), Quobyte:(*v1.QuobyteVolumeSource)(nil), AzureDisk:(*v1.AzureDiskVolumeSource)(nil), PhotonPersistentDisk:(*v1.PhotonPersistentDiskVolumeSource)(nil), Projected:(*v1.ProjectedVolumeSource)(nil), PortworxVolume:(*v1.PortworxVolumeSource)(nil), ScaleIO:(*v1.ScaleIOVolumeSource)(nil), StorageOS:(*v1.StorageOSVolumeSource)(nil), CSI:(*v1.CSIVolumeSource)(nil), Ephemeral:(*v1.EphemeralVolumeSource)(nil)}}}, InitContainers:[]v1.Container(nil), Containers:[]v1.Container{v1.Container{Name:\"pod-name-nginx\", Image:\"10.86.40.52:9443/gyf/nginx:1.17.1\", Command:[]string(nil), Args:[]string(nil), WorkingDir:\"\", Ports:[]v1.ContainerPort{v1.ContainerPort{Name:\"\", HostPort:0, ContainerPort:80, Protocol:\"TCP\", HostIP:\"\"}}, EnvFrom:[]v1.EnvFromSource(nil), Env:[]v1.EnvVar(nil), Resources:v1.ResourceRequirements{Limits:v1.ResourceList(nil), Requests:v1.ResourceList(nil)}, VolumeMounts:[]v1.VolumeMount{v1.VolumeMount{Name:\"default-token-tkjfj\", ReadOnly:true, MountPath:\"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount\", SubPath:\"\", MountPropagation:(*v1.MountPropagationMode)(nil), SubPathExpr:\"\"}}, VolumeDevices:[]v1.VolumeDevice(nil), LivenessProbe:(*v1.Probe)(nil), ReadinessProbe:(*v1.Probe)(nil), StartupProbe:(*v1.Probe)(nil), Lifecycle:(*v1.Lifecycle)(nil), TerminationMessagePath:\"/dev/termination-log\", TerminationMessagePolicy:\"File\", ImagePullPolicy:\"IfNotPresent\", SecurityContext:(*v1.SecurityContext)(nil), Stdin:false, StdinOnce:false, TTY:false}}, EphemeralContainers:[]v1.EphemeralContainer(nil), RestartPolicy:\"Always\", TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(0xc0007a0af8), ActiveDeadlineSeconds:(*int64)(nil), DNSPolicy:\"ClusterFirst\", NodeSelector:map[string]string(nil), ServiceAccountName:\"default\", DeprecatedServiceAccount:\"default\", AutomountServiceAccountToken:(*bool)(nil), NodeName:\"\", HostNetwork:false, HostPID:false, HostIPC:false, ShareProcessNamespace:(*bool)(nil), SecurityContext:(*v1.PodSecurityContext)(0xc00057c930), ImagePullSecrets:[]v1.LocalObjectReference(nil), Hostname:\"\", Subdomain:\"\", Affinity:(*v1.Affinity)(nil), SchedulerName:\"default-scheduler\", Tolerations:[]v1.Toleration{v1.Toleration{Key:\"node.kubernetes.io/not-ready\", Operator:\"Exists\", Value:\"\", Effect:\"NoExecute\", TolerationSeconds:(*int64)(0xc0007a0b80)}, v1.Toleration{Key:\"node.kubernetes.io/unreachable\", Operator:\"Exists\", Value:\"\", Effect:\"NoExecute\", TolerationSeconds:(*int64)(0xc0007a0ba0)}}, HostAliases:[]v1.HostAlias(nil), PriorityClassName:\"\", Priority:(*int32)(0xc0007a0bb0), DNSConfig:(*v1.PodDNSConfig)(nil), ReadinessGates:[]v1.PodReadinessGate(nil), RuntimeClassName:(*string)(nil), EnableServiceLinks:(*bool)(0xc0007a0bb4), PreemptionPolicy:(*v1.PreemptionPolicy)(nil), Overhead:v1.ResourceList(nil), TopologySpreadConstraints:[]v1.TopologySpreadConstraint(nil), SetHostnameAsFQDN:(*bool)(nil)}, Status:v1.PodStatus{Phase:\"\", Conditions:[]v1.PodCondition(nil), Message:\"\", Reason:\"\", NominatedNodeName:\"\", HostIP:\"\", PodIP:\"\", PodIPs:[]v1.PodIP(nil), StartTime:(*v1.Time)(nil), InitContainerStatuses:[]v1.ContainerStatus(nil), ContainerStatuses:[]v1.ContainerStatus(nil), QOSClass:\"\", EphemeralContainerStatuses:[]v1.ContainerStatus(nil)}}"}
```

How can I get it? I really appreciate any help with this.

PS: [referenced project](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/master/examples/builtins/mutatingwebhook.go)

Comment: Need some background information on this. Looks like you are intercepting the request to the API server with a mutation webhook. If the pod is yet to be scheduled by the API server to run on a particular node/kubelet - How would you to expect the namespace information to be updated?

Comment: At the time of interception, the only details that are valid are Pod spec, the status information wouldn't be updated

Comment: @Inian Yes, I am intercepting the pod creation request. I hope to implement different **container injections** by setting different rules by pod `names and namespaces`, such as injecting a specific namespace into container A, and injecting pods with a specific name prefix into container B.

Comment: Now I can know part of the pod name with [this code](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/pkg/kube/inject/inject.go#L827), but for the namespace, I haven't found how to get